# SQL : query that only contain one word

Tags: sql, wildcard

i want to select name that only contain one word with *SQL* wildcards..

i have tried

```
select name from employee where name not like '% %'
```

it works,but i wonder if there are other ways to do it using *SQL* wildcards

note : i am a college student,i am studying wildcards right now . i was just wonder if there are other ways to show data that only contain one word with wildcards except the above..

Comment: What's your ultimate purpose of the query? This search can be terribly slow if you are searching through many records.

Comment: my purpose was only for learning sql wildcards

Comment: You should take Gedrox idea. That's what I'd do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method makes proper use of wildcards, alternatively you could do it with CHARINDEX or similar function depending on RDBMS

```
select name 
from employee 
where CHARINDEX(' ',name) = 0
```

Likewise the patindex function or similar use wildcards, but that's pretty much the same as CHARINDEX, just allows for patterns, so if looking for multiple spaces it would be helpful.  I don't think there's much in the way of variation from your method for using wildcards.

Comment: @projek This is also a worthwhile technique since you're only learning. But for really large record sets this can be pretty slow. Perhaps you should build the index using this method.

Comment: thanks but i know how to do it with charindex,i was just wondering can i do it with wildcards but with other way..

Answer (score 2):

If you have large database I would suggest to create new indexed column `word_count` which would be autofilled by insert/update trigger. Thus you will be able to search for such records more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way I'd do it using wildcards. The other way would be:

```
select name 
from employee 
where charindex(' ', name) = 0
```